# Add blog languages to blog-name inside my-site-list in admin-bar

Tags: multisite, multi-language, admin-bar

I would like to add the language of every blog to the blogname inside the my-site-list inside the admin-bar.

The result should look like this:
[image]

For adding the languages to to the site-name in (1) I use this code:

```
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'add_language_to_blog_name');
function add_language_to_blog_name( $wp_admin_bar ) {

    global $wp_admin_bar;

    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'id'    => 'site-name',
        'title' => get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . ' | ' . get_bloginfo( 'language' ),
    ) );

}
```

How can I edit the blognames inside the my-site-list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little tricky, and I don't know if I got the best solution for this. However, it works.

The trick is, I use the same hook as you do, `wp_before_admin_bar_render`. In there I get all the elements, and check them if they have the parent `my-sites-list`.

If they do, I switch to the blog, get the language of the current blog, create the title and **call restore_current_blog()**.

After that, I create a *new admin bar item*, containing all the original information but the new title, remove the old one and insert the new one right afterwards.

#### Issues/concernces

- I could not find out by now if there is a way to get a blogs language without switching to it.
- Maybe there is a filter for the generation of the admin bar menu items. It would be much better to filter those titles there than manipulating them afterwards.

#### The function

```
function f711_tweaked_admin_bar() {

    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $elements = $wp_admin_bar->get_nodes();
    foreach( $elements as $element ) {

        if ( $element->parent == 'my-sites-list' ) {

            // reduce the adminbar Id to the blog ID
            $idinteger = str_replace( 'blog-', '', $element->id );

            // Switch to the Blog, get the language option. If empty, it's English
            switch_to_blog( $idinteger );
                if ( get_option( 'WPLANG' ) != "" ) {
                    $language = get_option( 'WPLANG' );
                } else {
                    $language = 'en_EN';
                }
                //set the new title for the Admin Menu
                $newtitle = $element->title . ' - ' . $language;
            restore_current_blog();

            // define new menu element
            $args = array(
                'title'     => $newtitle,
                'id'        => $element->id,
                'parent'    => $element->parent,
                'href'      => $element->href,
            );
            // remove the old one
            $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( $element->id );
            // add the new one right afterwards.
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );

        }

    }

}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'f711_tweaked_admin_bar' );
```